# How to check for errors on xcode disconnected devices?

Tags: swift, crash

I'm testing it by building an app on my iPhone device with xcode.
An iPhone app that has been disconnected from xcode works for a few days, and then turns off when you run the app.

I don't see my app name in the analysis log in iPhone privacy, and after syncing with mac, I can't check the error in logs> crashReporter.... How do I check the wrong part of my code?

Comment: Use crashlytics : https://firebase.google.com/products/crashlytics

Comment: Thx for answer!
i success to install crashlytics!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect the Xcode debugger to a running process or you can also have Xcode wait for a process to launch before connecting. Either way use the Xcode Debug menu to attach the debugger to a process (If you want to set some breakpoints for when the App is launched you can do that also) :-

[image]

If the App is not yet running you will need to attach to it by name. For example, here I am going to attach to the AdaptType project:

[image]

If the process is not running the Xcode debugger will wait for it to start. This is useful if you want the App to launch in response to an external event such as a notification :

[image]

If the App is already running you can connect to it directly either by name or finding it in the list of running processes. Make sure you have the device or simulator selected as the target of your Xcode project then use the “Attach to Process” option in the Debug menu:

[image]

Xcode suggests the most likely process based on your current Xcode project and destination or you can find it in the list of running processes. Once attached you can debug as usual. The debugger will stop if it hits a breakpoint or you can use the view debugger to inspect the view hierarchy.

More info can be find here :

1. https://useyourloaf.com/blog/connecting-xcode-to-a-running-process/
2. https://medium.com/better-programming/attach-a-debugger-to-your-ios-app-whenever-you-want-feca0c4f336b

Comment: hank you for answer.
There is a part I don't understand.

After connecting the device to xcode and rebuilding the app, do I have to name it by running Xcode> Debug> Attach to Process by PID or Name...? Or should I run Xcode> Debug> Attach to Process by PID or Name... without rebuilding?

When I run Xcode> Debug> Attach to Process by PID or Name..., only the message Waiting to attach to ......on iPhone appears in xcode. Is it running properly?

Comment: You don't need to rebuild. You connect your device, do Xcode> Debug> Attach to Process by PID or Name and then just open the app.